# Firebase test-lab "uploaded APK does not specify a main launcher activity"

Tags: android, firebase, testing, firebase-test-lab

I'm trying to use the firebase test lab for the first time to test my android app in other devices but an error called "uploaded APK does not specify a main launcher activity" pops up, i don't know why. The app runs fine on our devices and on the play store.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mJUKh.png)

Anyone have any suggestions about it? Thank you so much